# How do I provision a Apple device using Apples Member Center (new interface update 4/6/2013)

Tags: ios

So it seems like Apple updated the member center, and I'm having a hard time trying to add a device to one of my current provisioning profiles.

Previously it was possible to do this by clicking on the provisioning profile, and then selecting "edit" where you would have a list of all your devices and can add whichever ones you'd like to the provisioning profile.

After the member center update (4/6/2013), when you select on the "provisioning profile" there is no location where your devices are listed & can be added to that profile as it was setup before. I need to add a device to the provisioning profile to export and then import into testflight for testing & distribution.

I know this is possible through Xcode, but I'd like to do this the through Member Center (if it's still possible)

Thanks,
Russell Bradley

Comment: Hello Russell, and welcome to AskDifferent! This site purpose is to help consumers troubleshoot problems they may have with their apple hardware/software, and is not really focused on coding-related affairs. I suggest you try also posting this question in Stackoverflow, which is a specialized Stackexchange site exclusively for coding-related questions. I am confident you will find more qualified people to answer your question there!

Comment: This seems to have answered my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868114/how-to-add-a-device-to-an-existing-ad-hoc-provisioning-profile

Comment: Great! Glad you found an answer to your question! :)